# (24-EDO) Microtonal chord symbols for these chords

Tags: notation, chords, chord-theory, microtonality, quarter-tones

I came across some interesting chords recently in a series talking about 19-EDO but I found that a lot of them work quite well in 24-EDO as well, and they are shown below. I can get behind everything in 19, where the diminished third is between a minor third and a whole tone. But in 24-EDO, things are different, as the diminished third is enharmonically equivalent to the whole tone with a subminor third being a semidiminished third instead.

What would be the chord symbols of these chords:

1. [C][D half sharp][E half sharp][G] (supermajor second + whole tone + supermajor second)
2. [C][E half sharp][A] (two supermajor thirds)
3. [C][E half sharp][A][C sharp-and-a-half] (three supermajor thirds)
4. [A][C half flat][D][F half flat][G] (four subminor thirds or "half-fourths")

Whereas I can easily tell what [C][E half flat][G][B half flat][D] is. That's a stack of four neutral thirds, giving a neutral 9 chord.

There seems to be no standardised way of notating chords you don't find in 12-EDO. Could anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: This page has a ton of symbols for microtones, pick and choose? https://w3c.github.io/smufl/latest/